# Phonegap, open local Pdf file on Android 7

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, fileopener2

I have a cordova app with pdf's in it. Every year the pdf's need to be updated and there seems to be a new headache to get it working on Android.

On iOS I can open it with InAppBrowser and the relative url

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(URL,'_blank','closebuttoncaption=< Terug,toolbar=yes');
```

On android I used different methods, childbrowser, fileOpener2 and copying the file to externalDataDirectory

```
var uri = 'www/' + URL;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory +  uri, 
  function(fileEntry) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(dirEntry) {
      fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, uri.split('/').pop(), function(newFileEntry) {
        //window.open(newFileEntry.nativeURL, '_system');
        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(newFileEntry.nativeURL,'application/pdf');
      });
    });
  }, function(evt) {
    alert("Problem opening catalogus \n" +JSON.stringify(evt));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(evt));
  }
);
```

Latest solution was using

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

But google only excepts targetSdkVersion 26 now to the store

So any good working solutions out there?

I thought it was a common use case and simple to achieve, when I started out...

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explanation and workaround here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/386

I hope this will be fixed with a PR soon.